# setting background-color in IE via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to set a divs background color via

```
var color = "#FF0000";
$('#main_content_bg').css('background-color', color);
```

This works everywhere except IE (I have 8 installed);

The only thing I can think of is that I need to cast the color value to a number somehow.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?

thanks

Comment: seems to [work for me (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/y5PpP/)... could another part of your code be causing it to fail?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you put in your question, your problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, the color value was an array. Other browser took value at index 0 in the array - IE baulked. thanks

Comment: Check the developer tools' console to see if there's any error thrown by ie

Answer (score 0):

Why Dont you try with

$('#main_content_bg').addClass("The Class that set color");